# React portfolio copying images in ubuntu

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, ubuntu

I am getting a no file found error when trying to copy over images from my download folder to my project directory. I am running an ubuntu 22.04 LTE environment in windows.

I am using this command

```
cp helvetica-neu.ttf c/users/myname/portfolioapp/src/assets/images
```